# Control 'ctl07' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, runatserver

I have a problem you can see at the title.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:TextBox ID="mac_id" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="Temp Ekle" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

inside aspx.cs i create a table and i insert some values from database to this text box called "mac_id".

```
TableCell cel = new TableCell();
mac_id.Text = Convert.ToString(myDataTable.Rows[0][2]);
cel.Controls.Add(mac_id);
rw.Cells.Add(cel);
```

it is inside the form tag and it is runat="server".This is the code that using mac_id textbox.there is no code that manipulate that textbox.I only want to show the user the id.I am not using any render control or something that textbox has.I also check the other solutins but they are all using render or writer i am not thats because i open a new question.
I hope i can explain my problem enough.Thanks for helping.

Comment: what is `rw` in the last line?

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, you already have a TextBox mac_id and then you are trying to move the control into a table cell in code behind?  I would remove the TextBox in your aspx file and just create the Textbox control in code behind.

Comment: rw is my table row @mcalex i am trying now for the suggestion nicole

Comment: Your question is not at all descriptive to answer. Its quite hard to guess and answer, right ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this execption by overriding VerifyRenderingInServerForm

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
  /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
     server control at run time.
     Hence, no exception. */
}
```

Comment: You may also need to set `EnableEventValidation="false"` in the `<%@Page />` element. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28155089/153923