# Control 'ctl00' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got an error as shown below. Can anyone help me to fix the issue please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfEf6.png)

I tried adding form tag as

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<table border="0" class="forms">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" name="RadioButton1" id="ctl00_ctl36_g_ad6f39ad_7948_409d_ba2a_e8c922b9bcdf_RadioButton1" value="RFP" text="RFP" checked="true">
</asp:RadioButton>
</td>
<td>
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" name="RadioButton2" id="ctl00_ctl36_g_ad6f39ad_7948_409d_ba2a_e8c922b9bcdf_RadioButton2" value="RFQ" text="RFQ"></asp:RadioButton>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

still the issue persists. 
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I dont see any issue with your code. This must work. If you still have issue., Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957280/control-ctl07-of-type-textbox-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-se?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your support @Ratheesh.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your name properties are different.

> > are you using content template?